# Build and Debug Tomcat Source in Intellij

Tags: java, tomcat, intellij-idea, ant, tomcat9

I need to build and debug tomcat in intellij. I have tried a number of guides as noted below without much success.

**System Variables:**

- ANT_HOME = C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tomcat\apache-ant-1.10.9
- CATALINA_HOME = C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.41
- JAVA_HOME = C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_281
- PATH: ...;%JAVA_HOME%\bin;%ANT_HOME%\bin;%CATALINA_HOME%\bin

**File Paths:**

- C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tomcat\apache-ant-1.10.9
- C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.41
- C:\Users\User1\Desktop\Tomcat\apache-tomcat-9.0.41-src

**Intellij Version:** 2020.3.1

Possible solution ([LINK](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43888998/how-to-debug-tomcat-source-code-in-intellij-idea)) but how would you open up the project and how would you configure the run/debug? I believe this would work but I need a step-by-step guide on how to open this in intellij and how it can be built and debugged.

```
cd apache-tomcat-9.0.41-src
ant -buildfile build.xml ide-intellij
```

Alternative solutions but appear outdated:

- [Solution 1](https://www.programmersought.com/article/66456102742/)
- [Solution 2](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/206891315-Building-Tomcat-from-sources-with-Ant-and-Idea-)

Answer (score 1):

> how would you open up the project

To open the project you should be able to just use File | Open action in Intellij IDEA after running the `ant -buildfile build.xml ide-intellij`.

> how would you configure the run/debug?

Use steps from [RUNNING.txt](https://github.com/apache/tomcat/blob/master/RUNNING.txt) to set up teh all the environment variables and in Tomcat startup script catalina.sh script right above the first line that reverences the `JAVA_OPTS` variable, add this line:

```
JAVA_OPTS="$JAVA_OPTS -Xdebug -Xrunjdwp:transport=dt_socket,server=y,suspend=n,address=64998"
```

Now, restart Tomcat. Next, in IntelliJ, create a [Remote JVM Debug](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/run-debug-configuration-remote-debug.html) Run/Debug Configuration, enter the port just like in the command line (64998), save it and then press "Debug" in IDE

[image]

Comment: I have added the JAVA_OPTS line at 265 of "catalina.sh" file which is the first reference to the variable inside "apache-tomcat-9.0.41-src\bin". I then ran "startup.bat", then in IntelliJ, I created the new configuration ([Image](https://imgur.com/rn3xp6Z)), then clicked "Debug" icon next to "debug-tomcat-9" which produces "Unable to open debugger port" ([Image](https://imgur.com/mbLhHGd)). I have changed the port number on both sides to something else and this doesnt work either. Anything I am missing?

Comment: I have updated the answer. Make sure you have set up all environment variables as specificd in Tomcat `RUNNINT.txt` documentation and started the Tomcat startup script with needed JVM options for the remote debug - make sure you have set the correct JDK version in Remote Debug Configuration. See also this example for starting Tomact server with remote debug JVM options: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6734028/2000323

Comment: @Andrey Thank you for clarifying. I went through the Running.txt as suggested but I am still receiving the same error. Here are the steps I taken to configure on a fresh install of Windows today right up until I receive the error: [Link](https://imgur.com/a/LHYzRw9)